# Discord.js V14 interaction.editReply gives a invalid webhook token error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When I try to edit a reply to a slash command using `interaction.editReply()` after having deferred it using `interaction.deferReply()` I get a DiscordAPIError[50027]: Invalid Webhook Token.

The deferReply goes through without a problem because I do get the `bot is thinking...` message, but as soon as I call the editReply it triggers the error message. Using `interaction.reply()`does not throw this error, but I can not confidently say that all interactions can be replied to within 3 seconds because data has to be fetched from a database.

I am completely lost as to what could cause this error, especially because I can not remember changing anything in the code that could have any influence on this which is backed up by the fact that a older version of this project is giving me the same error while it did work literally yesterday.

Here is the full error message I am getting:

```
E:\OneDrive\Developing\Discord\JavaScript\Discord bot\Code\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:748
        throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50027]: Invalid Webhook Token
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (E:\OneDrive\Developing\Discord\JavaScript\Discord bot\Code\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:748:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (E:\OneDrive\Developing\Discord\JavaScript\Discord bot\Code\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:560:14)
    at async REST.request (E:\OneDrive\Developing\Discord\JavaScript\Discord bot\Code\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1000:22)
    at async InteractionWebhook.editMessage (E:\OneDrive\Developing\Discord\JavaScript\Discord bot\Code\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:324:15)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.editReply (E:\OneDrive\Developing\Discord\JavaScript\Discord bot\Code\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:150:21)
    at async E:\OneDrive\Developing\Discord\JavaScript\Discord bot\Code\commands\raids\account.js:68:21 {
  rawError: { message: 'Invalid Webhook Token', code: 50027 },
  code: 50027,
  status: 401,
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/997498462792859720/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTAwMDAyNTAzNTM0NTUxMDQxMDpvUEVwOXNZWEYwU2F3THFHazgyMGZESXIyOXpaS0Y0NE1IdHdZZzk4WjFnbmR2bVcyWU03SGF4bWhXbzF3S0NCREJqbzhQZmNTRUljV0U0N2dhR2xtNTNXRnBuNzg5ZGZ3M2lXN2NjQTgyUU1MbkhKdEE5NUVWRFIzM0NYdFo4WQ/messages/@original',
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [
        {
          title: 'Switch account',
          description: 'Choose your new active account from the list below.',
          color: 2132654
        }
      ],
      components: [ { type: 1, components: [ [Object] ] } ],
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: 64,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, everyone using the discord api is having this issue. It is now fixed.

### [2:12 PM](https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/1000027443270271066)

> Hi everyone. There is currently an issue being investigated with interaction edits, deletes, and followups. This issue results in receiving `50027: Invalid Webhook Token` errors when trying to edit, delete, follow up, or take some other actions on interaction webhooks.
> [image: And then there's Mason Today at 2:12 PM]

### [4:37 PM](https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/1000064059829395517)

> Webhook token problem has been identified and we are working on rolling out a fix. We will update this message when it is resolved.
> [image: And then there's Mason Today at 4:37PM]

### [5:43 PM](https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/1000080622393495633)

> The webhook token problem should be fixed.
>
> As a reminder, we saw a Snowflake length increase to 19 characters today!
> [image: Ian 2 aka Desch at 5:43PM]

Comment: Thank you so much, that must have been it. Could you please tell me how you got that message? I didn't see anything on the discord api status page.

Comment: Oh you just have to join the Discord official developper server ( https://discord.gg/discord-developers ) and go to #api-annoncements and you'll see it at the very bottom. The discord status page is mostly for the discord client (user interface) problems like connection problem for all discord users etc.. For developper problems, it's in that channel